# Android-x86 on QEMU on Windows

Tags: android, windows, virtualization, qemu, android-x86

I would like to launch Android_x86 on QEMU on Windows. I installed qemu for Windows to my computer and I tried to launch android on qemu. But it was failed. I can see the android text but QEMU can not start the Android OS.

[image: (screenshot goes here)]

What could be the problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why!! don't use qemu, it is really slow... Look for android emulators instead. Most apps will use mobile graphics as thats what most phones have, qemu will not emulate this, and that might cause the app you want to use to not function. I personally would have asked google "how to run android on qemu" as qemu doesn't care what os it is running on

Answer (score 0):

Try using an accelerator like [HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm) or the built-in accelerator, Windows Hypervisor Platform.